# Is there an easy way to apply a function to a subset of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Assume I have the following numpy array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]], [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]])
>>> arr
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]],
       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]]])
```

I would like map a function to a sub-part of the array, e.g.:

```
flip_sign = lambda x: x*(-1)
```

In my example, I would like to apply this function only to the second row, yielding:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8]],
       [[-1, -2, -3, -4],
        [-5, -6, -7, -8]]])
```

In essence I want to use something like

```
np.apply_along_axis(flip_sign, 1, arr)
```

but specifying an index along axis 0 (or a range of indices) where this function should be applied.

Of course I could split the array into subsets, then apply the function on the subset and concatenate the subsets again.
But is there a built-in (numpy) function that can easily do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your function is simple enough like multiplication or sum by scalars, you can directly apply it to the portion of the array

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]], [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]])
flip_sign = lambda x: x*(-1)
arr[1] = flip_sign( arr[1])
```

Output:

```
[[[ 1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8]]

 [[-1 -2 -3 -4]
  [-5 -6 -7 -8]]]
```

This works because of the way the overload of * + - / is implemented in numpy. If you perform any of this operations on an array, with a scalar, it will automatically perform the operation on every element of the array.

For more complex functions `np.apply_along_axes` can be used as such:

```
arr[1] = np.apply_along_axis( flip_sign, 0, arr[1])
```

Comment: great, thanks! That is what I was looking for.
But is there any reason why I couldn't do this with a more complex function (as long as it can take a 1-d array as input)?

Comment: Using apply_along_axes you can actually do this even with more complex functions